# How to get RavenDB to work with WCF Data Services?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, ravendb, odata

I use WCF Data Services 5.3.0 with Reflection Data Provider. My source data stored in RavenDB, so all my queries are deferred. So, are there some ways to call .ToList() for my query after OData filter applied and before results returned to client?

**UPDATE:** My DataModel Property declaration

```
    public IQueryable<PositionModel> Positions
    {
        get
        {
            using (var session = OLAPDocumentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                return session
                    .Query<ConsolidatedApplicationPosition>()
                    .Select(x => new PositionModel
                                     {
                                         ApplicationId = x.ApplicationId,
                                         CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                                         ID = x.Id,
                                         Platform = x.Platform,
                                         Position = x.Position,
                                         RegionalCode = x.RegionalCode,
                                         Timestamp = x.Timestamp,
                                         TopListId = x.TopListId
                                     })
                    .AsQueryable();
            }
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION** See @matt-johnson answer, and don't forget to add [DataMember] to all properties in model

```
[DataContract, DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class PositionModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Position { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RegionalCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TopListId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OData requires an `IQueryable`, which is deferred by design.  Show some code if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Updated question with some source code.

Comment: The `.AsQueryable()` is redundant here.  You can leave it off.  Was there some other part of your question?  I am not sure what you want to do.  What doesn't work?

Comment: Current code always produces empty list, until i call .ToList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had to go refresh my memory about how WCF Data Services works.  Shawn Wildermuth has [an excellent example video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601461).

The main problem is that you are trying to transform the query client-side with the `Select` statement.  When you return an `IQueryable`, that is supposed to hook directly in to the linq provider - in this case, the output of the RavenDB query.  You can apply `Where` and `OrderBy` filters, but you cannot do a projection with a `Select` statement.  That breaks the query chain.

So if you want to project from your `ConsolidatedApplicationPosition` object that you have in the database to the `PositionModel` object that you are returning to WCF Data Services, you are going to have to do it another way.  Here are some options:

1. If all of the fields that you need projected are already in the source data, then you can just do:

   ```
   return session.Query<ConsolidatedApplicationPosition>()
                 .AsProjection<PositionModel>();
   ```

   The only problem here is that your identifiers don't match up.  Raven's default identifier convention is `Id` (Pascal case) while WCF's is `ID` (upper case).  You can line them up either by changing Raven's convention:

   ```
   DocumentStore.Conventions.FindIdentityProperty = x => x.Name == "ID";
   ```

   or by changing WCF's convention with the `DataServiceKey` attribute:

   ```
   [DataContract, DataServiceKey("Id")]
   public class PositionModel
   {
       [DataMember]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. If you want to keep the identifiers mismatched, or if you want to transform more fields, you won't be able to use a dynamic index.  Instead, you'll have to create a static index and use a transform to control the projection:

   ```
   public class YourIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ConsolidatedApplicationPosition>
   {
     public YourIndex()
     {
       Map = docs =>
         from doc in docs
         select new
         {
           // You need to map any fields that you might query
           // or sort on through the odata filters.
         };

       TransformResults = (database, docs) =>
         from doc in docs
         select new PositionModel
         {
           // if you need integer identifiers in your result,
           // you'll have to split them from the doc key, like this:
           ID = int.Parse(doc.Id.ToString().Split('/')[1]),

           // otherwise, just do this:
           ID = doc.Id,

           // bring over all of your other fields as well
           Platform = doc.Platform
           ... etc ...

        };
     }
   }
   ```

   After you have the index in place, you would query it like this:

   ```
   return session.Query<PositionModel, YourIndex>();
   ```

With either option, there is no select statement in the query, so there's no need to do `ToList` or `AsQueryable`.  You are simply sending the `IQueryable` interface of the RavenDB linq provider into the WCF Data Service context.

Comment: Also worth noting, they are working on separating transforms from indexes for RavenDB 2.5 (not yet released).  That will allow you to do a transform against a dynamic index instead of having to make a static one.  [Read here for more details.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ravendb/w9Diy8ub5OM/discussion)

Comment: Thank toy for response. It's very useful. But my problem was different (updated quastion)

Comment: @JiříGluškov  - I read your update, and that is not true.  An empty lucene query returns ALL data.

Comment: It's very strabge, i discovered it with Fiddler. Also i discovered, that with not empty query parameter in request to the RavenDB server response was correct.

Comment: @JiříGluškov - Read through my answer carefully.  It's because of the `Select` you are doing which breaks the query.

Comment: .Query<ConsolidatedApplicationPosition>().AsProjection<PositionModel>() return list of PositionModel objects with default properties: {"Id":"ConsolidatedApplicationPositions/1000000","ApplicationId":null,"CategoryId":null,"Platform":null,"Position":0,"RegionalCode":null,"Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","TopListId":null},{"Id":"ConsolidatedApplicationPositions/1000001","ApplicationId":null,"CategoryId":null,"Platform":null,"Position":0,"RegionalCode":null,"Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","TopListId":null} and so on

Comment: @JiříGluškov - then the field names are not lining up. They must match exactly, and are case sensitive.  If you can't do that, you need to take option #2 and use a transform.

Comment: I couldn't get WCF to work with string ids.  Try it with just integer ids.  Also, you need `[DataMember]` on every property, not just the id.